# clear buffer contents in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, buffer, ar.drone

I am working on a program where I continously  send control commands to control the AR.Drone. I am writing the contents to a buffer and sending to a socket.
When I execute the program the drone is  not behaving as required. I think this may be due to contents queued in the buffer that were not sent.
So I want to clear the contents of buffer before sending any new command. How can I do this?
In C we can use `flush()`. What is it in C#?
My code is:

```
    Socket sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    IPAddress send_to = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
    IPEndPoint sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to, 5556);
    string buff1;
    byte[] buff2;
```

I am writing a string to a text file upon each button press. I then read the text file to retrieve the content and based upon the content send the corresponding command.And in text file each time I am overwriting the previous string so there will be only one string in text file.

```
    switch (choice1)
                    {
                        case "takeoff":
                            {

                                System.Console.WriteLine("send take-off command");
                                buff1 = null;
                                buff2 = null;
                                buff1 = String.Format("AT*REF={0},290718208\r", seq);
                                buff2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buff1);
                                sending_socket.SendTo(buff2, sending_end_point);
                                seq = seq + 1;
                                break;
```

Comment: You don't show anything that relates to transmission. Do you have a `Stream` or `Socket` or something somewhere? The thing you need to flush(if this is the cause) is that.

Comment: Also you say "the drone is behaving as required", so it works ok?

Comment: yes I have a  UDP socket.

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to clear the contents of buffer before sending any new command.

In the code shown, you are creating a new buffer each time. There is no need to clear / reset / flush this.

---

You mention a `Socket`; in that case, there's a good chance this is Nagle. Try setting:

```
socket.NoDelay = true;
```

Note that if you do this, it is your job to perform any necessary buffering *prior* to sending. Avoid things like:

```
netStream.Write(oneByte);
netStream.Write(threeBytes);
netStream.Write(twoBytes);
```

as this will lead to packet fragmentation. If you have existing code like that, a pragmatic fix is to wrap a `NetworkStream` in a `BufferedStream`, and `Flush()` that at the end of logical messages.

Comment: sorry the code I have posted is just an example of what I am doing. Actually I am initializing the buffer at the start and then write different commands on button press.

Comment: @wireless_lab so... until you show what you are *actually* doing, it is hard to comment; however, the basic version would be: when calling `Write` / `Send` / whatever, the buffer is allowed to be over-sized; the important bit is that you tell it how much of the buffer is actual content. But again: can't comment without an example of how you are sending.